# PHP_BINDIR неправильно показывает путь

Tags: php

Знаю , что по этому поводу много уже задано вопросов , и найдено ответов , но я  эту проблему никак не могу решить . **PHP_BINDIR** показывает неверный путь к исполняемому файлу -  **C:\php** .В свою очередь **PHP_BINARY** показывает правильно ***D:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP-5.6\php.exe*** . Переменная окружения PATH настроена тоже верно . Использую openserver 5.2.2 . В чем может быть причина ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё просто.

`PHP_BINDIR` - Константа которая записывается при компиляции. Если хотите другое значение,  качаем исходники и компилируем с параметром `--prefix` с указанием нужной папки.

По умолчанию стандартный php устанавливается в `c:\php` поэтому компилируется с соответствующим значением.
Похоже ребята которые собирают openserver по этому поводу не парятся.

`PHP_BINARY` - Получает значение при запуске скрипта, поэтому показывает всё правильно.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35460541/1843389

Если нужно получить имя папки то можно использовать функцию `dirname()`

```
diname(PHP_BINARY);
```

Comment: получается  , что нужно php устанавливать отдельно от опенсервера ?

Comment: Этой Константин просто нельзя доверять. Так как значение пишется при компиляции. Пользуйтесь `dirname(PHP_BINARY);`

Comment: хорошо . т.е значение должно быть что-то типа D:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP-5.6\ ?

Comment: Да. Не совсем понятно зачем вам нужно это значение, но будет типа того. Без `\\` на конце.

Comment: мне просто нужно вызвать консольную команду , чтобы запустить сервер . использую для этого скрипт сторонний и там используется php_bindir

Comment: Дополнил ответ. dirname должно помочь.

Comment: извиняюсь , но php_binary в опенсервере показывает такой путь D:\openserver\modules\http\Apache-2.4\bin\httpd.exe . Это разве верно ? если запускаю скрипт в виндовской консоли то путь D:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP-5.6\php.exe

Comment: Верно. Потому что в первом случае скрипт запускает apache(httpd)  через php "plugin", а во втором сам интерпретатор. В вашем случае, лучший вариант создать конфигурационный файл и прописать путь туда. Если скрипт будет запускаться по разному.

Comment: но в опенсервере  D:\openserver\modules\http\Apache-2.4\bin не работает  .Вся консольная команда получается такой start /b D:\openserver\modules\http\Apache-2.4\bin/php /shop/_protected/yii push/index r